# App Certificate Issue Android

Tags: android, apk

I published an app a month ago and now I need to update it, but I am also making a free version of that app. So I finished it yesterday but by mistake I signed it with the key of the paid apk. So now I am trying to sign the original apk which needs to be updated but when I try to install it says `"Application cannot be installed because a application with same certificate is conflicting..."`.

If I upload that apk will it cause any issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you will upload that new apk, it will cause issue, the user will not be able to install it, reason being app signed with one key needs to use the same key in the future builds

See the following quote from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/)

> As you release updates to your application, you must continue to sign
>   the updates with the same certificate or set of certificates, if you
>   want users to be able to upgrade seamlessly to the new version. When
>   the system is installing an update to an application, it compares the
>   certificate(s) in the new version with those in the existing version.
>   If the certificates match exactly, including both the certificate data
>   and order, then the system allows the update. If you sign the new
>   version without using matching certificates, you must also assign a
>   different package name to the application — in this case, the user
>   installs the new version as a completely new application.

Read more here at Android Developer-[Signing Strategies](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies)

Comment: like i developed a app and its released ok and its paid.. and after some time i developed the free version so by mistake i signed it with the key of previous one.And now i need to update the paid version so if i sign it will it cause any issue. free version has not been published yet

Comment: it is quite simple 1. use the 1 certificate per application
2. if you are publishing different apk, use different package name for both of those.

Comment: so if i sign the paid version with the original key and if sign the free version with different package name and with different key.. ??

Comment: precisely, you have not published the free apk, so you have less to worry and also keep in mind about the `version number` and `version code` in manifest before updating.

Comment: ok.. now i signed the paid one with the original key with different version name and code and it's installing well.. :) and one thing more

Comment: Is there any rule for version names like if i created version 1.1 so the next version has to be 1.2 >?? is it ??

Comment: i want to ask some thing that why my service notification is showing only for minutes and it vanishes ?? in previous version it was showing well ?? wat could be the reason ?? code is same and i have declared it in manifest ?? ??

Comment: @user3148503 friend, it would be nice if you ask separate question for it, never mind , As user i do not like persistent notification, unless it is really required, cause that makes notification panel cluttered with lots of notification, just permanently there, but if you want it use `notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)` , think of use case before adding that feature

Answer (score 0):

You need to change package name and update version name and version code in android mainfest file after that again create new signed key , no need to use old key for sign in .

If you are using old key for sing in and upload that apk on market then you can not upload app on market because it conflict package name.
So remove all the issue you need to generate new key with changes package name ,version name and version code also.

Hope this will help you.